# strtof- return a wrong number

Tags: c, string

edit-

### So I understand that there is no solution to this problem. Does anyone know a function in C that returns the 31-38 index from the array(str)?

Hey i have a problem with strtof function and i cant find a solution to the problem on the Internet, Can anyone help please?

here a simple function:

```
float getCord(int placeOnArray, char str[80]){
   char str2[7];
   for (int i=placeOnArray ;i<placeOnArray+7;i++){
      str2[i-placeOnArray]=str[i];
   }
   float f1;
   f1=strtof(str2,NULL);
   return f1;

    }
```

the input- str= ATOM      1  N   ASN A   1      -4.890 -12.296 -15.280  1.00 30.36           N 
,  place on array=31

The desired result: -4.890
,the returned result: -4.88999987

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: ... and there is no `strtolf`, did you mean `strtof`?

Comment: Use `double` and `strtod`. It looks like floating point problem.

Comment: yes strtof. sorry

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that floating-point math is inherently inexact?

Comment: @papi read [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588014/898348)

Comment: same problem with strtod

Comment: Round to 3 digits and you are fine.

Comment: Try `printf("%6.3f\n", -4.88999987); /* -4.890 */` See [code running on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/0t1LY8)

Comment: @user3121023 yes but here it's not really important because `strtof` will stop at the  `' '` anyways. But the code is admittedly sloppy.

Comment: @user3121023 you're right, but anyway there is no need to copy anything, you can call `strtof` directly on the pointer into the original string

Comment: @papi ... and `place on array=31`: shouldn't it be 19 instead of 31?

Comment: @papi not the answer to your question, but your `getCord` function is wrong, see  user3121023's comments. This is simpler and works. `float getCord(int placeOnArray, char str[]) {
  return strtof(str + placeOnArray, NULL);
}`

Comment: So I understand that there is no solution to this problem. Does anyone know a function in C that returns the 31-38 index from the array(str)?

Comment: @Jabberwocky thank you!

Comment: @papi no, there is no solution, because there is no problem. See my answer.

Comment: *"Does anyone know a function in C that returns the 31-38 index from the array(str)?"* Maybe `strncpy(dst, src + 31, 8); dst[8] = 0;`

Comment: @papi your edit completly changed the meaning of the question....

Answer (score 1):

`strtof` works as expected:

Consisder this little program:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () 
{
  float f = strtof("4.890", NULL);
  printf("%10.10f\n", f);
}
```

The output is:

```
4.8899998665
```

---

There is no exact representation of `4.890` in floating point. You need to read this SO article:

- [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/898348)

Also your `getCord` function is wrong:

This is a simpler and correct alternative:

```
float getCord(int placeOnArray, char str[]) {
  return strtof(str + placeOnArray, NULL);
}
```

There is no need to extract the string representing the number, you can directly scan for the number in the original string. `strtof` will stop at the first character different from `0`-`9` and `'.'`. Change the first line in the program above to `float f = strtof("4.890    ", NULL);`, the output will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

> desired result: -4.890 ,the returned result: -4.88999987

There will always be some error in a floating point operation. This is expected and should be taken care of by the programmer.

That is why you cannot use `f1==f2` for floating point numbers. You need to check that the numbers are within the given error range. For floats this is `FLT_EPSILON`

Answer (score 0):

```
//
//  main.c
//
//
//  Created by myhaspl on 2018/10/22.
//   myhaspl@myhaspl.com.
//   https://dmyhaspl.github.io/
//

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
char mytoken[10];
char* getCord(int placeOnArray, char mystr[80]){
    const char s[2] = " ";
    char str2[7];

    char* token=mytoken;
    for (int i=placeOnArray ;i<placeOnArray+7;i++){
        str2[i-placeOnArray]=mystr[i];
    }
    strcpy(mytoken,strtok(str2, s));
    printf("%s\n",mytoken);
    return mytoken;
}
int main(){
    char str[80] = "ATOM 1 N ASN A 1 -4.890 -12.296 -15.280 1.00 30.36 N";
    char* token=getCord(17,str);
    printf("%s\n",token);
    float number=atof(token);
    printf( "%f\n", number );
    return 0;
}

-4.890
-4.890
-4.890000
```